# Excel VBA: Does Cutting Autofill Areas in Halves or Fourths reduce Calculation Time for large areas?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to code an Efficiency program in excel VBA that basically searches through an adjecent worksheet for three matching criterion and pulls from a fourth column if they match.  This is done by using the CountIf Function.  For every time the the three columns match, the value in the fourth column is added.  This is completed using a SumIf function.  I am autofilling this CountIf(SumIf()) function across a 100+ row, 5000+ column area.

As of now the code is taking ~45 minutes just to compute that.  I was wondering if I cut the area into 4 separate calculations or recoded my equation, I could cut down this run time?  As you can see by the end of my code, I complete another calculation to show an average of every column which adds on even more time.

Here is my Code:

```
Sheets("8MO Raw Data").Select
Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Select
EightMOLastRow = ActiveCell.Row

Sheets("Shop Average Calc").Select

Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Select
ShopAverageLastRow = ActiveCell.Row

Range("B3") = "=IF(COUNTIFS('8MO Raw Data'!$D$2:$D$" & EightMOLastRow & ",B$1,'8MO Raw Data'!$F$2:$F$" & EightMOLastRow & ",B$2,'8MO Raw Data'!$B$2:$B$" & EightMOLastRow & ",$A3)=0,0,((SUMIFS('8MO Raw Data'!$Q$2:$Q$" & EightMOLastRow & ",'8MO Raw Data'!$D$2:$D$" & EightMOLastRow & ",B$1,'8MO Raw Data'!$F$2:$F$" & EightMOLastRow & ",B$2,'8MO Raw Data'!$B$2:$B$" & EightMOLastRow & ",$A3))))"


Range("B2").End(xlToRight).Select
ShopAverageLastColumn = ActiveCell.Column


Range("B3").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(3, 2), Cells(3, ShopAverageLastColumn)), Type:=xlFillDefault

Range(Cells(3, 2), Cells(3, ShopAverageLastColumn)).Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(3, 2), Cells(ShopAverageLastRow, ShopAverageLastColumn)), Type:=xlFillDefault


Cells(ShopAverageLastRow + 1, 1) = "Sum of Hrs/pc"
Cells(ShopAverageLastRow + 2, 1) = "#OP Completed"
Cells(ShopAverageLastRow + 3, 1) = "Average Hrs/Pc"

Range("B" & ShopAverageLastRow + 1) = "=SUM(B3:B" & ShopAverageLastRow & ")"
Range("B" & ShopAverageLastRow + 2) = "=COUNTIFS('8MO Raw Data'!$D$2:$D$" & EightMOLastRow & ",B1,'8MO Raw Data'!$F$2:$F$" & EightMOLastRow & ",B2)"
Range("B" & ShopAverageLastRow + 3) = "=B" & ShopAverageLastRow + 1 & "/B" & ShopAverageLastRow + 2 & ""

Range(Cells(ShopAverageLastRow + 1, 2), Cells(ShopAverageLastRow + 3, 2)).Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(ShopAverageLastRow + 1, 2), Cells(ShopAverageLastRow + 3, ShopAverageLastColumn)), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

Answer (score 1):

All the .`select`s ......

An easy thing you could try is put this in the beginning

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

And reverse that when the function is complete

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

That will stop Excel from showing you all the changes that it is making on screen which can take up a good chuck of time.

*But*

You shouldnt really need to do that anyway since you could remove many if not all the select statements.

```
Range(Cells(3, 2), Cells(3, ShopAverageLastColumn)).Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(3, 2), Cells(ShopAverageLastRow, ShopAverageLastColumn)), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

Could be reduced to the following and function just the same.

```
Range(Cells(3, 2), Cells(3, ShopAverageLastColumn)).AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(3, 2), Cells(ShopAverageLastRow, ShopAverageLastColumn)), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

I would like to think some of the time could be saved with one or both of those suggestions.

Comment: Thanks! I applied the screen updating code and removed a lot of the .selects, however, the code still takes around 40 minutes to run.  The code itself might just take a while to run due to the searching it requires, but I'm surprised there isn't any way to reduce the time even by a few minutes.